# AS3 How to set cursor property move

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor, mouse

I am unable to set my flash cursor from auto to move, any help ?

```
private function itemCursorMove(e:MouseEvent){

Mouse.cursor = "move";

e.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,itemCursorAuto);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually `registerCursor()` a "move" cursor. In order to register a new mouse cursor, you need to have:

1. A vector of bitmap images that contain cursor shapes. Can have a length of 1, with a single shape. Maximal bitmap size is 32x32.
2. A defined hotspot (the point which actually interacts with environment), you manually define it basing on your images.
3. A combined `MouseCursorData` object, filled with this data. [Description here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MouseCursorData.html). You just create it, fill its properties and pass it to...
4. A `Mouse.registerCursor()` call. [The manual is here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html#registerCursor%28%29). In short, you provide it a String that will be the name of the cursor, and a prepared object.

This is only needed to be done once at initialization. An example:

```
var mcd:MouseCursorData=new MouseCursorData();
mcd.data=Vector.<BitmapData>([new MyCursorImage().bitmapData]); // a single image
// MyCursorImage is an asset of type Bitmap
mcd.hotSpot=new Point(); // top left corner is action point
Mouse.registerCursor("move",mcd);
```